# Ajax posting to incorrect URL in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I have page which Ajax loads a view into a Bootstrap modal and then calls a jQuery.validate and this works, but only on the first instance. After that, when the form changes, and the URL changes in the Ajax call, it then still attempts to POST to the previous url used.

I've confirmed the URL has changed using console, I just can't get my head around why it is doing this, I've never had this problem before, and seems to only be happening with POST requests.

Code below...

Press button and load a particular modal view from Laravel Blade, in this case the options view (/lead/options)

```
success: function(result) {
    modal.form.attr('id', widget + 'Lead');
    modal.load.html(result);
    if(widget == 'update'){                     
         modal.dialog.addClass('modal-lg');
         modal.title.text("Edit Lead");
         modal.save.text("Update Lead").removeClass('hide');
         _validateModalForm(widget, modal, lead);
         return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This calls the _validateModalForm with the parameters, code below:

```
_validateModalForm = function(formID, modal, lead){
        console.log(formID);
        var formID = formID;
        var lead = lead || '';
        var prevComplete = 0;
        var formURL = 'leads';
        if(lead != ''){
            formURL = formURL + '/' + lead;
        }
        formURL = formURL + '/' + formID;
        console.log(formURL);
        console.log('form#' + formID + 'Lead');
        $('form#' + formID + 'Lead').validate({
            invalidHandler: function () { //display error alert on form submit              
                EMPGlobal.showAlert(modal.message, '', 'danger', 'There was an error, please check the form, correct, and try again.' , '', '', '', 'warning');
            },
            submitHandler: function (form){ 
                var formData = new FormData($(form)[0]);
                var fileUploadBar = $('#' + formID + 'LeadProgress div.progress-bar');
                $.ajax({
                    url: formURL,
                    data: formData,
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    xhr: function(){
                        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                        fileUploadBar.parents('div.progress').removeClass('hide');
                        //Upload progress
                        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
                            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                                var percentComplete = evt.total / evt.loaded;
                                if( percentComplete > prevComplete){
                                    //Do something with upload progress
                                    fileUploadBar.css('width', percentComplete.toFixed(0) + '%');
                                    prevComplete = percentComplete;
                                } else if( percentComplete == 1) {
                                    fileUploadBar.css('width', '100%');
                                }
                            }
                        }, false);
                        return xhr;
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        EMPGlobal.showAlert('', '', 'success', result, '', '', '', 'success');
                        $('form#' + formID + 'Lead').validate('destroy');
                        modal.show.modal('toggle');
                        return false;
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        var returnMes = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                        var messages = '';
                        $.each(returnMes, function(i,v){
                            messages = messages + v + '<br>';
                        });
                        returnMes = messages;
                        message = 'A ' + jqXHR.status + ' ' + errorThrown + ' error occured. <br> <i>Message Details: <br> ' + returnMes + '</i>';
                        EMPGlobal.showAlert(modal.message, '', 'danger', message, '', '', '', 'warning', jqXHR.status);
                        if(fileUploadBar.length){
                            fileUploadBar.css('width', '0%');
                            fileUploadBar.parents('div.progress').addClass('hide');
                        }
                    },
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

This works. The modal closes, and if this time I press the send button...

```
if(widget == 'send'){
    modal.dialog.addClass('modal-md');
    modal.title.text("Send Permission Form");
    modal.save.text("Send");
    _validateModalForm(widget, modal, lead);
    return false;
}
```

and then press submit on the form again, it then tries to post to /leads/{leadid}/update

Here is the output of the above steps in the console, as per the console.log lines:

```
update
leads.js:192 leads/1xXpM0O7PYO/update
leads.js:193 form#updateLead
leads.js:183 send
leads.js:192 leads/1xXpM0O7PYO/send
leads.js:193 form#sendLead
VM5400:1 POST http://ml.energynet.app/sales/leads/1xXpM0O7PYO/update 400 (Bad Request)
(anonymous) @ VM5400:1
send @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
submitHandler @ leads.js:201
d @ VM5441:4
(anonymous) @ VM5441:4
dispatch @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3
```

Any ideas as to what is causing this? This can happen in any order too, say I do Send first, and then Update, I run into the Update trying to post to /send

Hoping this is clear enough. If not, let me know and I will try and make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after posting the question after being frustrated with it for an hour, I've resolved it after trying one thing that popped into my head.

I used $.ajaxSetup, before the submitHandler used $.ajax and it has resolved the problem.

Code below:

```
_validateModalForm = function(formID, modal, lead){
        var formID = formID;
        var lead = lead || '';
        var prevComplete = 0;
        var formURL = 'leads';
        if(lead != ''){
            formURL = formURL + '/' + lead;
        }
        formURL = formURL + '/' + formID;
        $.ajaxSetup({
            url: formURL,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
        });
        $('form#' + formID + 'Lead').validate({
            invalidHandler: function () { //display error alert on form submit              
                EMPGlobal.showAlert(modal.message, '', 'danger', 'There was an error, please check the form, correct, and try again.' , '', '', '', 'warning');
            },
            submitHandler: function (form){ 
                var formData = new FormData($(form)[0]);
                var fileUploadBar = $('#' + formID + 'LeadProgress div.progress-bar');
                $.ajax({
                    data: formData,
```

I'm not sure why this works, and perhaps someone can put in an explanation as to why it works, all I can assume is it must clear some sort of cache, but yippee it works!

Hopefully this will help anyone else with similar problems.